FastAPI deployed to azure web app failing to load
Been fighting with getting a FastAPI  app to run on azure. Here is all the steps and findings:
FastAPI  endpoints:
from fastapi import FastAPI,Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi_azure_auth import SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Security
import os
from typing import Dict

from settings import Settings

from pydantic import AnyHttpUrl,BaseModel

from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import AsyncGenerator

from fastapi_azure_auth.user import User

settings = Settings()

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI) -> AsyncGenerator[None, None]:
    """
    Load OpenID config on startup.
    """
    await azure_scheme.openid_config.load_config()
    yield


app = FastAPI(
    swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url='/oauth2-redirect',
    swagger_ui_init_oauth={
        'usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant': True,
        'clientId': settings.OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID,
        'scopes': settings.SCOPE_NAME,
    },
)

if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=[str(origin) for origin in settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=['*'],
        allow_headers=['*'],
    )

azure_scheme = SingleTenantAzureAuthorizationCodeBearer(
    app_client_id=settings.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    tenant_id=settings.TENANT_ID,
    scopes=settings.SCOPES,
)

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    roles: list[str] = []


@app.get("/", dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme)])
async def root():
    print("Yo bro")
    return {"whoIsTheBest": "DNA Team is"}

@app.get("/test", dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme)])
async def root():
    print("Yo test")
    return {"whoIsTheBest": "DNA Team is!"}

@app.get("/me", dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme)])
async def me(request: Request):
    print("Me")
    return User(roles=request.state.user.roles,name=request.state.user.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app', reload=True) 

Settings:
from pydantic import AnyHttpUrl, computed_field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
import os

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS: list[str | AnyHttpUrl] = ['http://localhost:80']
    OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID: str = os.getenv('OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID')
    APP_CLIENT_ID: str = os.getenv('APP_CLIENT_ID')
    TENANT_ID: str = os.getenv('TENANT_ID')
    SCOPE_DESCRIPTION: str = "user_impersonation"

    @computed_field
    @property
    def SCOPE_NAME(self) -> str:
        return f'api://{self.APP_CLIENT_ID}/{self.SCOPE_DESCRIPTION}'

    @computed_field
    @property
    def SCOPES(self) -> dict:
        return {
            self.SCOPE_NAME: self.SCOPE_DESCRIPTION,
        }

    @computed_field
    @property
    def OPENAPI_TOKEN_URL(self) -> str:
        return f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{self.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    class Config:
        env_file = '.env'
        env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
        case_sensitive = True

I have following action in github:
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - fast-api-port
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: '3.12'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_7C6D249DE594426EBD4725CC0D066145 }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_6399B578ADAF41E095CA377A465B8BB1 }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_527AF2EA4A6A4A8BAC99ECB57B6CE6AB }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'fast-api-port'
          slot-name: 'Production'

I can see files get deployed to output.tar.gz file in the wwwroot folder in the web app as expected.
I added following to the Configration on the web app:

When I load my app https://xxx.westeurope-01.azurewebsites.net/docs I get following error:

This is what I could find in logs:

Any suggestions what can cause this?

please provide error in text format.

The traceback says your "TENANT_ID" is "None" - start there. How are you setting your environment variables?

@Thomas Segato The environment variables are not being fetched correctly, try setting them in the Environment Variables section of the Azure Web App.

I got the same error when I used your code and deployed it to Azure using GitHub.
If we carefully observe the application logs, we can see that the environment variables OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID, APP_CLIENT_ID, and TENANT_ID have their input_value set to None. For this reason, the app didn't start.
To resolve the above issue, I added the following values from the .env file to the Environment Variables of the Azure Web App.
TENANT_ID=<Tenant_Id>
APP_CLIENT_ID=<App_Client_Id>
OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID=<Openapi_Client_Id>


Azure Output:


@Thomas Segato Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
